# How would I pass viewmodel class to repository class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a viewmodel class for my custom view template. Right now I am calling the database save method in Controller class. Now I would like to move this logic to the Repository class. How can I access my viewModel properities in my repository class? I appreciate any input. Thank you.

Here is my code.

ViewModel

```
    public SelectList StatusList { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Required")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

My Contoller class:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // go and save your view model data  
            using (var adapter = new DataAccessAdapter())
            {
                    TestEntity test1 = new TestEntity();
                    test1.statusId = Convert.ToInt32(viewModel.Status);
                    adapter.SaveEntity(test1);

                    TestEntity1 test2 = new TestEntity2();
                    test2.mId = test1.mId;
                    test2.startDate = viewModel.startDate;
                    adapter.SaveEntity(test2);
           }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to access your view model properties in your repository, you want to map the view model properties back onto your entity class and pass the entity to your repository. The entity should be in a library known to both the MVC application and your data library.

```
public class TestController
{
  public ITestRepository _repository;

  public TestController(ITestRepository repository)
  {
    _repository = repository;
  }

  public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel viewModel)
  {
    var entity = new TestEntity()
      { statusId = Int32.Parse(viewModel.Status) };
    var entity2 = new TestEntity2()
      { mId = entity.mId,
        startDate = viewModel.startDate };

    _repository.SaveEntity(entity);
    _repository.SaveEntity2(entity2);
  }
}
```

Comment: One question. In my case TestEntity() and TestEntity2() are the database tables. I can save directly by calling .save method. Why do I need Repository class? I am confused.

Comment: Do I have to reference my database classes in Controller class?

Comment: You had stated in the question that you had a repository class, so I inferred... I would recommend abstracting your data access behind an interface (or repository class) and then use a dependency injection framework to pass in an implementation of that abstraction. If that sounds like too much work, or you don't know what I'm talking about and you just want to get some work done. Then reference your data access in your controller. There's nothing wrong with that approach.

Comment: Something also be worthwhile: Let your ViewModel have a constructor that takes in the entity model as a parameter, thus removing the mapping logic from your controller. You can also then create a 'MapTo' function on your ViewModel that returns a new instance of the entity model. This lets you easily translate models back and forth without adding extra logic to the. Check out AutoMapper as well: http://automapper.codeplex.com/ .. it greatly helps with automating this process.

Comment: @Thechoyce: I'm assuming you meant "This lets you easily translate models back and forth without adding extra logic to the **controller**"  If not, could you please clarify?